# What is this equivalent to FontAwesome to display a country icon?

Tags: icons

On this website : https://www.lemanegeabijoux.com

At the top, we can see an icon of France, it seems to be a font icon like FontAwesome, but I can't find what it is.

I see font family "mab" but nothing is found on Google... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the gist of how they do it:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mab';
  src: url("fonts/mab.eot?pihty9");
  src: url("fonts/mab.eot?pihty9#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/mab.ttf?pihty9") format("truetype"), url("fonts/mab.woff?pihty9") format("woff"), url("fonts/mab.svg?pihty9#mab") format("svg");
}
[class^="ico-"], [class*=" ico-"] {
  font-family: 'mab' !important;
}
.ico-france:before {
  content: "\2b1f";
}
```

```html
<i class="ico-france"></i>
```

It won't work here (you'll get a pentagon instead), since this site doesn't have the `mab` font available at that URL.

Given the font is called `mab`, and that site is "le **M**anège **à** **B**ijoux", I'm going to go with "it's a custom in-house font they made themselves". However, this should still be enough information for you to reproduce the effect yourself if you want.